# Render table row by key from list of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

I'm trying to bind my data to a `blueprint.js` `Table` , however the docs are unclear on how to do this. How do I create a custom render function for a `blueprint.js` `Table` to render the key from a list of objects?

In the example `rowIndex` is passed by default.

The code:

```
data = [
  { name: "L/S", col2: "abc" }, 
  { name: "HY", col2: "def" }
];

myRender = (rowIndex: number, key: string) => {
  return <Cell> {this.data[rowIndex][key]} </Cell>;
};

<Table numRows={2}>
  <Column name="not-working" cellRenderer={this.myRender("name")} />
  <Column name="not-working2" cellRenderer={this.myRender("col2")} />
</Table>;
```

The error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

  18 | 
  19 | myRender = (rowIndex: number, key: string) => {
> 20 |   return <Cell> {this.data[rowIndex][key]} </Cell>;
     |                                     ^
  21 | };
```

See example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k9l9q2150r

The docs:
https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table.basic-usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cellRenderer` expects a function which takes a `rowIndex` as an argument. So this is what you need to do:

```
myRender = (key: string) => (rowIndex: number) => {
  return <Cell>{this.data[rowIndex][key]}</Cell>;
};
```

And here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y19jp659l)